# What is an offsite facility as per PCI DSS requirement 9.5.1?

Tags: pci-dss, backup

PCI DSS Version 3.0, Requirement 9.5.1 says that we have to store media backups in a secure location, preferably an off-site facility such as an alternative or backup site or a commercial storage facility.

I don't understand this requirement. What is an offsite facility for data protection?

How do you store the media backups using an offsite facility?

When I searched for offsite facility for media backups, I saw offsite data protection in the below link.
[Offsite Data Protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-site_data_protection) but I still don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requirement appears to relate to backup media (e.g. tapes/disks etc) which you may have as part of your backup regime.

The idea here is that you shouldn't store backup media on the same site as the systems they are backing up as in the event of an outage at the main site, you may not have access to the backups either (which makes them less useful to you).

So if you store them at another physical location, they will still be available to you in the event of a disaster at the main site.

In terms of complying with the requirement, you may well find that a disaster recovery company or backup company (in the UK Iron Mountain is a good example) will provide a service where they will securely store backup tapes for you.

An alternative, if you have multiple physical locations, is to store tapes at other sites you own.  However this does add some additional complications as you'll need to make sure that you transport and store the tapes securely, to avoid the risk of losing them.

All this assumes that you're backing up to removable media. If you're doing online backups (e.g backup to the cloud) none of this is relevant as you don't have backup media to manage!

Comment: Just to add a more concrete response to this @Rory excellent explanation. You don't need to look for an "media storage place", you just can rent a box room and store the media in there (you might have to properly set up the room). Or, if you have different offices use both to have respective backups.

Comment: @kiBytes what is a box room?

Comment: @RajeshKannan it is a place where people store things that they normally don't use, it is also called a sideboard or a junk room.